# users keep getting logged out on heroku node.js app

Tags: heroku

```
const signToken = id => {
  return jwt.sign({ id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
    expiresIn: process.env.JWT_EXPIRES_IN
  });
};

const createSendToken = (user, statusCode, req, res) => {
  const token = signToken(user._id);

  res.cookie('jwt', token, {
    expires: new Date(
      Date.now() + process.env.JWT_COOKIE_EXPIRES_IN * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
    ),
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: req.secure || req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] === 'https'
  });

  // Remove password from output
  user.password = undefined;

  res.status(statusCode).json({
    status: 'success',
    token,
    data: {
      user
    }
  });
};
```

I have deployed my app to heroku.
To test I login as a existing test user
The login is successful but then I get logged out after redirecting.
It works fine on my local and i even configured my app.js to trust proxies.

can someone help?

Comment: This likely has to do with how you're handling sessions. Please [edit] your question to include the relevant portion of your code _here_, as part of your question. See [ask].

Comment: Check your browser's request / response section to see if your [cookie](https://github.com/greentea-latte/blissful-retreats/blob/master/controllers/authController.js#L18) is actually being set properly, and if its then being sent back to the server.

Answer (score 0):

it was an issue with my routes. all fixed now !